Lstlisting - how to add keywords in the environment header
I set my lst (in Java language) to have some additional keywords with different styles. Now, inside the document, i would like to add more keywords to a single listing because JetBrains does highlight static fields and methods. These "keywords" are simple words, like "counter", "time" or "song", and i don't want to highlight them all aross my document, so i figured i would do that in environment header. Also i would like them to have different style than standard keyword, as defined in lstset keywordstyle = [3]\color{Purple}\bfseries. Unfortunately, it seems like there is no way to do that, as an error pops out:
Use of \lst@MakeMoreKeywords doesn't match its definition.
<argument> 3\relax \lst@MakeMoreKeywords \relax

It looks like there is no command morekeyword=[<number>]{<word>} with an argument, but only when its written in enviroment. What's interesting, plain morekeyword={<word>} does work.
What am I doing wrong? Is there some way to do that? Below example that does work:
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper, english, polish]{article}

\usepackage{fullpage}
\usepackage[polish]{babel}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage[table,usenames,dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{listings}


\lstset{ 
    language=Java,
    basicstyle=\ttfamily,
    keywordstyle=\color{RoyalBlue}\bfseries,
    otherkeywords = {length\ },
    morekeywords = {record,var},
    morekeywords = [2]{@Override},
    keywordstyle = [2]{\color{Dandelion}\bfseries},
    morekeywords = [3]{length\ },
    keywordstyle = [3]\color{Purple}\bfseries,
    rulecolor=\color{gray},
    rulesepcolor=\color{gray},
    backgroundcolor=\color{white},
    frame=shadowbox,
    numbers=none,
    framexleftmargin=1em,
    xleftmargin={\dimexpr 1em+3pt},
    framerule=0.01pt,
    framextopmargin=1ex,
    framexbottommargin=1ex,
}


\begin{document}

\begin{lstlisting}[morekeywords={bar}]
var
@Override
foo.length
bar
\end{lstlisting}

\end{document}


Welcome to TeX.SE!

You can use morekeywords={[3]{bar}}. This will avoid the problem of using ] inside of an optional argument.
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper, english, polish]{article}

\usepackage{fullpage}
\usepackage[polish]{babel}
\usepackage[table,usenames,dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{listings}


\lstset{ 
    language=Java,
    basicstyle=\ttfamily,
    keywordstyle=\color{RoyalBlue}\bfseries,
    otherkeywords = {length\ },
    morekeywords = {record,var},
    morekeywords = [2]{@Override},
    keywordstyle = [2]{\color{Dandelion}\bfseries},
    morekeywords = [3]{length\ },
    keywordstyle = [3]\color{Purple}\bfseries,
    rulecolor=\color{gray},
    rulesepcolor=\color{gray},
    backgroundcolor=\color{white},
    frame=shadowbox,
    numbers=none,
    framexleftmargin=1em,
    xleftmargin={\dimexpr 1em+3pt},
    framerule=0.01pt,
    framextopmargin=1ex,
    framexbottommargin=1ex,
}


\begin{document}

\begin{lstlisting}[morekeywords={[3]{bar}}]
var
@Override
foo.length
bar
\end{lstlisting}

\end{document}


